# Rest arguments not working for gtag setup

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-analytics

I am trying to make a Google Tag loading script work, using TS.

```
  const GTAG_ID = 'ID';

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GTAG_ID}`;
  script.async = true;

  document.head.appendChild(script);

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }

  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', GTAG_ID, { send_page_view: false });
  gtag('event', 'page_view');
```

The code above works and the gtag event fires. However, if I want the gtag function to be typed (somewhat), this would be the approach.

```
  function gtag(...args: Array<unknown>) {
    window.dataLayer.push(args);
  }
```

However, when using this approach, the gtag event **does not fire**. No console errors. It doesn't matter if I spread the second `args` or not. This leaves me scratching my head. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's probably a type issue since Google expects following format for events: `dataLayer.push({'event': 'event_name'});`